# Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.27.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a requirement to implement gmail into my web application. While implementing Gmail in my web application, I am getting the mentioned exception.

I have tried the steps mentioned in Gmail API Quickstart...
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet

As I am trying to create an object of GmailService, I am getting an exception. My code is as follows...

```
    static UserCredential GetGmailUserCredential()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        string[] scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
        string credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json");
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"D:\Projects_Temp\Learning\Webform\GSuite\client_secret.json", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    scopes,
                    Environment.UserName,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientID, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                         , scopes
                                                                                         , Environment.UserName
                                                                                         , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                         , new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        return credential;
    }

    public static GmailService GetGmailClient()
    {
        var credential = GetGmailUserCredential();
        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });

        return service;
    }

    public static List<Label> GetLabels(GmailService service)
    {
        // Define parameters of request.
        UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");
        // List labels.
        return request.Execute().Labels.ToList();
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (GmailService service = GSuiteHelper.GetGmailClient())
            {
                var lst = GSuiteHelper.GetLabels(service);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you install the nuget package?  What type of project have you created and what framework are you targeting?   Also note as stated in the tutorial that code is designed for a "simple .NET console application"  Its not going to work with a web app.

Comment: This example is not working in Console app too. And yes, I've done all the things mentioned in the article. I've already implemented Google Drive & Google Calendar by same way & they are working. Only this feature is not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Web.config of your web application. I saw a duplicate entry in mine. One had all caps public token. So I am guessing it is case sensitive and didn't over-write when I upgraded the version. So it kept using the old version number, which I had obviously uninstalled.
Hope this helps.
These was the duplicate that existed.

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" publicKeyToken="4B01FA6E34DB77AB" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.27.1.0" newVersion="1.27.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```